# How to find the smallest integer that, when multiplied to a list of floats, makes all values integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, numpy, integer

I am trying to write a function that returns the value of the smallest integer that needs to be multiplied for a list of floats to be all integers. I tried implementing something with the "Least Common Multiple," but I'm not sure if the math checks out...

Say I have the following list (or list-like object) of float values:

```
example = [0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]
```

How could I write a function that returns `func(example) = 10` ?

Another example would be...

```
example = [0.05, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8]

> func(example)
20
```

Since...

```
> 20 * np.array(example)
np.array([1, 2, 14, 16])
```

And all are integers.

Comment: `1/min([0.4, 0.5])` isn't an integer.

Comment: Yes, the key here is integer. Sorry.

Comment: Where do the `float`s come from? If you can create `Decimal` instances instead, you can get the denominator in lowest common terms using the `as_integer_ratio` method, then compute the LCM of all the denominators.

Comment: You'll first need a way to arbitrarily convert floats into rational numbers, which isn't actually possible, so really we just need to know which small cheats are permitted. Not enough information in the question.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Of course it's possible: a float is a dyadic rational by definition. The issue is knowing which rational a float is supposed to represent: is `0.4` supposed to be `2/5`, or `3602879701896397/9007199254740992` (per `decimal.Decimal(.4).as_integer_ratio()`)?

Comment: okay, I could have worded it better. The point is, it needs something like what chepner said earlier using Decimal. "float" is a problem here.

Comment: Also, are you assuming values are "exact" to some number of digits, or would you like `[0.33333333333, 0.5]` to return 6 rather than some large power of 10?

Answer (score 1):

Find the largest decimal places, multiply it to the list, find gcd, and find the minimum integer multiplier.

```
import numpy as np
import decimal
from math import gcd
from functools import reduce

def find_gcd(lst):
    x = reduce(gcd, lst)
    return x


example = [0.05, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
decimal_places = min([decimal.Decimal(str(val)).as_tuple().exponent for val in example])
x1 = np.array(example)
multiplier = 1/(10**decimal_places)
gcd_val = find_gcd(map(int, x1 * multiplier))
min_multipler = int(multiplier/gcd_val)
print('Minimum Integer Multipler: ',  min_multipler)
```

If you don't like Decimal.

```
example = [0.05, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
n_places = max([len(str(val).split('.')[1]) for val in example])
multiplier = 10**n_places
x1 = np.array(example)
gcd_val = find_gcd(map(int, x1 * multiplier))
min_multipler = int(multiplier/gcd_val)
print('Minimum Integer Multipler: ',  min_multipler)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an upper bound `den_max` on plausible denominators the `fractions.Fraction` class has a handy `limit_denominator` method.

For example:

```
import fractions

max_den = 1000

fractions.Fraction(1/3)
# probably not what we want
# Fraction(6004799503160661, 18014398509481984)

fractions.Fraction(1/3).limit_denominator(max_den)
# better
# Fraction(1, 3)

import sympy

example = [0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]

sympy.lcm([fractions.Fraction(x).limit_denominator(max_den).denominator for x in example])
# 10

example = [0.05, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8]

sympy.lcm([fractions.Fraction(x).limit_denominator(max_den).denominator for x in example])
# 20
```